# Проблема с выводом

Tags: java

Только недавно начал изучать Java и решил сделать простенькую игру по угадыванию буквы, но столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

```
    import java.io.IOException;
public class home {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        double otwet;
        int i = 0;
        int a = 65;
        int b = 25;
        char People,Answer;
        People = ' ' ;
        otwet = a + (int) (Math.random() * b);
        System.out.println(otwet);
        Answer = (char) otwet;
        System.out.println(Answer);
        do { System.out.print("Введите символ: ");
        People = (char)System.in.read();
        if (Answer == People) {
            System.out.println("Молодец!");
            i = 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Нет, ошиблись!");
        }
        } while (i != 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем заключается небольшая проблема нам нужно самим догадаться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программа выполняется, и выдает результат. Или вас тревожит то-что пишет некоторые фразы пишутся 2 раза? ТО вот исправленный код (Немного удобнее сделал)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double otwet;
    int i = 0;
    int a = 65;
    int b = 25;
    char People, Answer;

    otwet = a + (int) (Math.random() * b);
    Answer = (char) otwet;
    System.out.println("Введите этот символ: " + Answer);
    if (i < 2) {
        System.out.print("Введите символ: ");
        People = (char) System.in.read();
        if (Answer == People) {
            System.out.println("Молодец!");
            i = 2;

        }
        if (Answer != People) {
            System.out.println("Нет, ошиблись!  Game Over"");
        }
    }
  }
```